Config update to stop connection to https://dev.datasqrl.com/ during datasqrl compilation
Can we update any config to stop connection to https://dev.datasqrl.com/ ? I dont have access to http://dev.datasqrl.com from execution system, so need to stop connection this external link to avoid compile failure
command: docker run -it -p 8888:8888 -v $PWD:/build datasqrl/cmd compile metrics/metrics.sqrl
